# Como inverter lista de controles do Control.ControlCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, aplicação-desktop

Estou inserindo em um Panel varias Labels, conforme vou inserindo, a primeira Label torna a ficar por ultimo no Panel. Mas eu queria reverter esse processo. Queria que a primeira Label que foi inserida, ficasse em primeiro lugar no Panel, e não ficasse em última.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl;
    Panel pn = new Panel();
    pn.AutoScroll = true;
    pn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        lbl.Text = i.ToString();
        pn.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
    this.Controls.Add(pn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que o que identifica/distingue o Label é o seu texto(`lbl.Text = i.ToString();`), então é só "inverter" o `for`:

```
for(int i = 12; i >= 0; i--)
```